# Android (JUCE) performance issues when NOT touching screen

Tags: android, c++, juce, oboe

I'm porting an iOS app made in JUCE over to Android (currently in Beta).  I have some strange behaviour where I get audio glitches and GUI frame drops which only appear when NOT touching the screen.

The app uses OBOE with JUCE 5.4.0 and is compiled for Android 8.0 and above only. Strangely this issue only occurs on a Galaxy S9 (tests are ok on Note 8, Note 9, Xiaomi mi A1 and some other devices). I've tried with a fresh factory reset on the Galaxy S9.

I'm new to Android development.

Comment: Have you tried on a different S9? Perhaps there's a hardware fault with just that one.

Answer (score 0):

What you are experiencing is likely to be the CPU frequency scaler on the Galaxy S9 which is aggressively scaling down the CPU frequency when the screen is not being touched. This leads to insufficient computational bandwidth causing your app to take too long inside the audio callback leading to underruns/glitches.

To verify this [use systrace and the Android Studio profiler](https://youtu.be/tWBojmBpS74?t=1670). The systrace will show you both audio underruns and the CPU frequency.

Tap on the screen during the trace and you should see the CPU frequency increase, and then drop soon after.

If this is the case there are few things you can try:

1. Ensure that you're using the most optimal compiler flags `-Ofast` or `-O3`
2. Use the recently released [`StabilizedCallback` class](https://github.com/google/oboe/blob/master/src/common/StabilizedCallback.cpp) in Oboe which was designed for exactly this purpose - it will attempt to keep the CPU spinning to avoid it being scaled down.
3. Monitor the underruns (obtainable through `AudioStream::getUnderruns()`) and scale back your computational load until you stop getting them.

If you still get issues publish your code, or atleast enough of it to reproduce the issue, on github and I'll try to take a look.

CPU frequency scaling is a pain for real-time apps which have significant cpu bandwidth requirements.

Comment: Thanks @donturner for the answer. 1. Didn't solve the issue unfortunately.  2. Sounds promising, do you have any suggestions of how to go about implement this in a JUCE app? I'm struggling to find any info on StabilizedCallback.

Comment: You'll need to modify the JUCE source (somewhere around here: https://github.com/WeAreROLI/JUCE/blob/master/modules/juce_audio_devices/native/juce_android_Oboe.cpp#L389) to wrap the existing callback in an `oboe::StabilizedCallback`. There's an example here: https://github.com/google/oboe/blob/master/samples/MegaDrone/src/main/cpp/AudioEngine.cpp#L29